# Some Doubts about Transaction Manager Configuration on Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Our team is currently developing an application that lies on 3 distinct datasources. So far so good, 
1st - Transaction Manager is the Primary (bean named transactionManager)
2nd - is sitting over a routingDataSource (provided by spring) with a transaction manager with a disntinc name. 
3rd - is a support database with another distinct transaction manager.

The problem resides now on delete.

I have the following method.
@Transactional("transactionManager")

```
    private void deleteInTransaction(Instance instance) {
        findById(instance.getId()).ifPresent(i ->delete(i));
    }
```

```
Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
    jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
    jpaPropertiesMap.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
    //TODO: renomear colunas no Entity e remover essa configuração.
    jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", true);
    jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"  , true);
    jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" , true);
    jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class" , "thread" );
```

Spring Framework is producing the following log.

**2021-03-27 12:39:12 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
2021-03-27 12:39:12 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
2021-03-27 12:39:16 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
2021-03-27 12:39:16 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - committing**

and its not deleting (note that hibernate debug log is activated.

My Transaction Manager (primary) configuration

````
    @Qualifier(value="transactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Autowired EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory,
            @Autowired DataSource dataSource) { 
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        txManager.setPersistenceUnitName("connemat");
        txManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        txManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
        return txManager; 
    }```

Any help will be very usefull. 

Not that i know that i have deleteById and other features but this will not solve the issue. 

Regards, 

Contnuing the evaluation of the problem i created a property map to configure the session context. 

I tried "thread" (which is the common sense) and the following error appear. 
**2021-03-27 13:38:07 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.unwrap(SessionImpl.java:3666)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCrea**
all options are throwing an error that the session is closed. 

Hum, any reason why?
````

Comment: I found the problem. quite odd.

Comment: the entity with problem is a "many" in a OneToMany with the "many eager". but the Set<Entity> at other was eager too. was good because i fixed some issues on configuration of AbstractRoutingDatasource

Comment: by the end "N transaction managers" and N EntiyManagers is not simple

Comment: nice article. https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth